# I want to integrate Medium's.com text editor in my Django Blog where users can write articles thoroughly?

Tags: javascript, text-editor, rich-text-editor

First of all  use medium's editor thoroughly if you didn't before, I want as it is that of Editor, if user want to upload image then editor save image, video etc on its own server then provide us images videos link by `img` tag..

Answer (score 1):

I've done this previously using [TinyMCE](https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You need to add tinymce js link in you base html and initialize tinymce in template where user will be writing post. An example of template you can [see](https://github.com/prachijustin/WebsiteUsingDjango/blob/master/AdminDashboard/templates/add_post.html).

This is how the [post](https://prachi-demo-web.herokuapp.com/front/39/post_detail/) looks.